# How to use Quicktime in Qt Qwebview?

Tags: html, qt, qt5, quicktime, qwebview

How can I use the Quicktime plugin inside a qwebview?
at the moment, when I go on a website with a quicktime video, all I get is this sign:

[image: plugin missing]

and this error in the Qt Application output:

```
Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Any idea how to include the quicktime video playback?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: this scenario is on 10.6.